# CodeIgniter redirect loop in subfolder on server

Tags: codeigniter

I'm stuck with redirect loop when I deploy the files from localhost to my server.

```
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

The site is multilingual and I'm using .htaccess file to remove the index.php from the uri. I'm trying to deploy the site to a subfolder in my domain (i.e http://www.mydomain.com/subfolder) and ideally I want the urls like this (http://www.mydomain.com/subfolder/en/welcome)

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have also tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mydomain.com/subfolder/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

My routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['^../products/(:num)'] = "products/products_list/index/$1";
$route['^../products'] = "products/products_list/index";

$route['^../products/detail/(:num)'] = "products/product/index/$1";
$route['^../(.+)$'] = "$2";
```

And finally MY_Config class for i18n:

```
class MY_Config extends CI_Config {

function site_url($uri = '')
{    
    if (is_array($uri))
    {
        $uri = implode('/', $uri);
    }

    if (function_exists('get_instance'))        
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $uri = $CI->lang->localized($uri);            
    }

    return parent::site_url($uri);
}

}
```

This setup works fine in my local environment, I access via http://local.subfolder.com, I set a virtual host to do this, but this setup doesn't work when I deploy to the server in a subfolder.

I would be really glad if someone can point where the problem is. Sorry for the long post, but wanted to give as much as information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'd try removing the trailing slash from `RewriteBase`

```
RewriteBase /subfolder
```

And also modifying your `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I've noticed that using the `?` before `/$1` seems to work sometimes in CI too.

Very useful doc:
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but actually changing the uri_protocol to REQUEST_URI did do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to use the htaccess for a particular folder., u just put your htaccess with in that folder. for ex.,

if ur using five virtual hosting like v1,v2,v3,v4,v5. And if u want to use your htaccess in v3, just put that file within that folder.